# relativity event coordinates

Tags: special-relativity

a man is standing at the origin. He has a clock. At a distance L from him, lies some dynamite sticks that he can explode using intense laser beam. He emits laser beam at t=0, the beam takes time t=L/c to reach the dynamite and explode it. The explosion is seen by the man after another L/c time because that will be the time taken by light from explosion to reach his eyes. Now, my question is: what is the event coordinates of explosion? is it (L,0,0,L/c) or (L,0,0,2.L/c)?

Comment: @Viktor answered your question perfectly, below. One event is when it exploded, another is when you observed it explode. It may have exploded and you didn't see it, and maybe nobody else either, it still happened at the spacetime coordinates pointed out by Viktor

Answer (score 1):

The event coordinates (in your notation) are $(L,0,0,L/c)$. There is another event: when the light from the explosion reaches the observer's eyes. The coordinates of this event in your reference frame are $(0,0,0,2L/c)$.